# How can I remove/reattach the clamp on a dishwasher hose?

Tags: dishwasher, plumbing-fixture

I'm trying to fit a dishwasher into our kitchen. There is a small gap in a counter top for the hose to go through, and the part of the hose that connects to the tap is too big to fit through... Is there some way I can disconnect and then reattach the fitting?

Here's a photo of two pipes with the fittings I can't get off:
[image: dishwasher hose with fittings]

Here's a photo of the hole I'm trying to get this pipe through (with the pipe alongside for size):

[image: hole in surface]

The irony of this is that I know I did this before as the dishwasher was plumbed in previously, but I can't remember how :(

Comment: Just enlarge the holes. The fittings are not designed to be removed from the hoses as you can see they are crimped on as part of the manufacturing process.

Comment: Right, I can do that if necessary. It's not the crimped on fittings I was hoping to remove, it's the screw on clamps - is that the correct word? Are those unremovable too?

Comment: Question.....The bottom side of your counter top is tiled and grouted with ceramic tiles???

Comment: No, it's just chipboard. I can cut through it if necessary. But I seem to have got this through before - perhaps it's my imagination

Comment: With regard to my question....the surface I am asking about is the one perpendicular to the panel with the hose notches in it.

Comment: Yes that perpendicular surface is ceramic tiles. That's the kitchen wall. The surface with the holes is a counter top with hardboard on to and chipboard beneath, and is horizontal. The dishwasher goes underneath

Comment: With regard to the screw fitting parts those are captured to the hose when the other part of the end piece is clamped to the hose. You could cut and peel off the metal crimp piece and then pull the barbed plastic end pieces out of the hose. But then on re-insertion you would have to use some hose gear clamps to reseal. In the end cutting the notches bigger is the easiest.

Comment: Ok thanks, just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything!

Comment: So is that horizontal panel with the notches/holes like inside a cabinet or is this ugly hose stuff showing at your counter level?

Comment: It is unfortunately ugly and visible :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can detach the board (assuming it isn't glued but screwed in place), put the pipe in place and re-attach the board over the pipes?

Comment: That is apparently the thing to do given what I asked above... what I ended up doing was different (see answer below)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to remove the board (which should be easy but involved unscrewing things and re-sealing as it goes towards the sink area), I actually just got a Y-connector and plugged the dishwasher in to the same outlet as the washing machine, below the surface. That means I don't have to rescrew the board in case of future changes ...

Of course, given my original question, removing the board was the only option :)

[image: Y-connector]